Is the map induced by the gradient flow on Wasserstein-2 space optimal transport map?
We know that the norm on the tangent space $T_\mu P_2$ is defined by
$$||\dot\mu||^2_{T_\mu P_2}=\inf\{\int |v|^2d\mu;\dot \mu+ \nabla\cdot(v\mu)=0\}
=\{\int |\nabla \psi|^2d\mu;\dot \mu+ \nabla\cdot(\nabla\psi\mu)=0\}$$
If we consider the probability flow induced by $\nabla\psi$:$$dx_t = \nabla\psi(t,x_t)dt,\text{with } Law(x_0)=\mu_0$$
then we can figure out $Law(x_1)=\mu_1$.
Let $x_t=T_t(x_0)$ denote the transport map between $\mu_0$ and $\mu_t$.My question is:Is $T_1(x_0)$ the optimal transport map between $\mu_0$ and $\mu_1$?
